# ngRoute not instantiated by karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, requirejs, karma-runner

### **Can anyone help me find a way to use both beforeEach(module()) and beforeEach(inject()) in the main describe() of my unit test?**

When I include both

```
beforeEach(module('ngRoute'));
```

and

```
beforeEach(inject(function () {}));
```

in the main describe() of my test file, I get this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngRoute&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20Module%20%27ngRoute%27%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.0-rc.2%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DngRoute%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:78:12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:1330:36%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:1268:38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:1328:14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:3071:26%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:224:11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:3065:5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fsocketwiz:8080%2Fbase%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1378401706000:3072:40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)). But, If I remove the beforeEach(inject () {})) code, then ngRoute is properly loaded by karma.

I have checked many other posts related to this issue. Such as:

- [Error: No module: ngRoute when trying to implement routing in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416575/error-no-module-ngroute-when-trying-to-implement-routing-in-angularjs)
- [AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr)
- [AngularJS 1.2 ngRoute unit test error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802342/angularjs-1-2-ngroute-unit-test-error)

As suggested by each of the above questions, I have made sure that angular-routes.js is included in my index.html and I have also made sure that 'ngRoute' is a dependency of my app.

**test file :**

```
define(['ngMock', 'controllers/home/main-home-ctrl'], function () {
    'use strict';

    describe.only('Controller: MainHomeController', function () {
        beforeEach(module('ngRoute'));
        beforeEach(inject(function () {}));

        afterEach(function() {

        });

        describe('', function () {
            it('should ', function () {

            });
        });

    });
});
```

**karma.config.js :**

```
files: [
            {pattern : 'www/js/bootstrap.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/lib/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/controllers/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/controllers/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/directives/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/directives/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/factories/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/factories/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/filters/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/filters/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/services/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www/js/services/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www-test/lib/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www-test/spec/**/*.js', included : false },
            {pattern : 'www-test/spec/**/**/*.js', included : false },
            'www-test/main-test.js',
            'www/js/lib/angular-route.js'
        ],
```

angular-routes.js is located at 'www/js/lib/angular-routes.js' and therefore should be included when karma runs my unit tests.

**app.js :**

```
    define([
        'angular',
        'angular-route',
        'controllers/index',
        'directives/index',
        'factories/index',
        'filters/index',
        'services/index'
    ], function (ng) {
        'use strict';
        return ng.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives', 'app.factories', 'app.filters', 'app.services']);
    });
```

Comment: If you never call `inject()`, you never push angular into the _"run"_ phase and so the module configuration code is never actually run. That's why there's no error when you remove `inject()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I found my rookie mistake.  Angular-route is being included in my production and dev code, but not in my test code because I only added the file to my production and dev folders.